# Cakephp how to join table on a specific field

Tags: cakephp, join

Someone can help me on this issue please?

How to join table on specific field?

I have 2 tables and I want to join them like this: Actus.user_id=>Follows.follower_id

---

**table 1 =>**

**Follows**

id
user_id
follower_id

---

**table 2 =>**

**Actus**

id
user_id
content
created

Comment: Do you mean that both models are not related and you want to perform an ad-hoc join?

Answer (score 0):

Forcing a join is done like this (on top of my head):

```
<?php 
    $results = $this->Actu->find('all',
        array('joins'=> array(
           'table'=>'followers',
           'type'=>'inner',
           'alias'=>'Follower',
           'conditions'=>array(
               'Follower.follow_id = Actu.user_id',
           )
         )
    )
?>
```

**But** you would normally don't need forcing joins. CakePhp can build this for you, if your Models (Actu and Follower) are declared properly. What about setting a `"Actu" hasMany "Follower"` relationship ? [See here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany)

**EDIT :**

I would do it like this (I am not sure about the exact model name, double check it) :

```
<?php
class Actu extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Follow'=> array(
            'className'     => 'Follow',
            'foreignKey'    => 'follower_id'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: How can i do for Follower hasMany Actu?

Comment: see my edited answer. For your error, maybe you should replace Follower by Follow in my example code